# A general formula for $\mathcal{F}_{n} = \prod_{i=1}^n (a_ix + b_iy)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, power-series, binomial-coefficients, products

So I am trying to simplify following product, $$\mathcal{F}_{n} = \prod_{i=1}^n \left(a_ix + b_iy\right)$$ in terms of products and summation. This is what I have come up with so far.

We see that for n=2, we get
$$\mathcal{F}_{2} = (a_1x + b_1y) \times (a_2x + b_2y) = a_1a_2x^2 + xy(a_1b_2+a_2b_1) + b_1b_2y^2$$

Likewise for n=3, we get
$$\mathcal{F}_{3} = a_1a_2a_3x^3 + x^2y(a_1a_2b_3+a_1a_3b_2+a_2a_3b_1) + xy^2(a_1b_2b_3+a_2b_1b_3+a_3b_1b_2) + b_1b_2b_3y^3$$

So the first and last term of $\mathcal{F}_{n}$ can be generalized to $\prod_{i=1}^n a_ix^n$ and $\prod_{i=1}^n b_iy^n$. Thus $\mathcal{F}_{n}$, can be given as,
$$\mathcal{F}_{n} = \prod_{i=1}^n a_ix^n + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(x^{n-i}y^i\right)\sum_{k=1}^{\binom{n}{i}}\mathcal{f}(a_{1,2\dots,n}, b_{1,2\dots,n})+ \prod_{i=1}^n b_iy^n$$
So I am stuck here I have come, I need to find this function $\mathcal{f}(a_{1,2\dots,n}, b_{1,2\dots,n})$ which will surely have some product operator inside. I have come up with one solution. Let n=4, and for i=1, term we get is
$$x^3y \sum_{k=1}^{\binom{4}{1} = 4} \prod_{m=1\backslash\{k\}}^{n=4}a_mb_k$$

Likewise for n=3, we get

$$xy^3 \sum_{k=1}^{\binom{4}{1} = 4} \prod_{m=1\backslash\{k\}}^{n=4}b_ma_k$$

I have not been able to come something similar for n=2, and then generalize it for all i and n.

Can some help, or provide some useful intuitions

Comment: $\mathcal{F}_{n} = a_1 \cdots a_n \prod_{i=1}^n \left(x + \frac{b_iy}{a_i}\right)$; and so the coefficients are then given by elementary symmetric functions of $\frac{b_iy}{a_i}$.

Comment: The problem is, I need to have product of $x$ and $y$. They have to be multiplied and then find the coefficients

Comment: I agree with @lhf ... learn about elementary symmetric functions.  Your solution can be given in in terms of them.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\ed{\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}}$
Will this do?
\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}_n&=\sum_{v\in\{0,1\}^n}\prod_{i=1}^n\big(a_ix\big)^{v_i}\big(b_iy\big)^{1-v_i}\\
&=\sum_{v\in\{0,1\}^n}x^\overline{v}y^{n-\overline{v}}\prod_{i=1}^na_i^{v_i}b_i^{1-v_i}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^nx^ky^{n-k}\sum_{v\in W_k}\prod_{i=1}^na_i^{v_i}b_i^{1-v_i}
\end{align}
where $\ \overline{v}\ed\sum_\limits{i=1}^nv_i\ $ and $\ W_k\ed\big\{\,v\in\{0,1\}^n\,\big|\,\overline{v}=k\,\big\}\ $ is the set of $\ n$-tuples of $\ \{0,1\}^n\ $ of total weight $\ k\ $.

Answer (score 0):

Another common way slightly different from the already given answer is using sets instead of $n$-tupels. We denote with $[n]:=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. We obtain
\begin{align*}
\prod_{i=1}^n\left(a_ix+b_iy\right)
&=\sum_{S\subseteq [n]}x^{|S|}\prod_{i\in S}a_iy^{n-|S|}\prod_{i\in[n]\setminus S}b_i\tag{1}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^nx^ky^{n-k}\sum_{{S\subseteq [n]}\atop{|S|=k}}\prod_{i\in S}a_i\prod_{i\in[n]\setminus S}b_i\tag{2}
\end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we sum over subsets $S\subseteq [n]$ which contain the indices with selected terms $a_ix$.
- In (2) we rearrange the sums according to the size of $S$.